# PHP - Convert data to valid json

Tags: php, json, validation

I have a huge .txt file with data in this format:

```
{
    "template_id": "prefix_1",
    "settings": {
        "setting1": "bla",
        "setting2": "blub"
    },
    "test": 1,
    "test": 2,
    "test": 3
},
{
    "template_id": "other_prefix_1",
    "values": {
        "value1": "bla",
        "value2": "blub"
    },
    "something": "Hello!"
},
{
    "template_id": "prefix_2",
    "settings": {
        "setting1": "bla",
        "setting2": "blub"
    },
    "test": 1,
    "test": 2,
    "test": 3
}
```

That looks like json, but it is not valid json and I want to make it valid. The result should be something like this:

```
{
    "prefix": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "settings": {
                "setting1": "bla",
                "setting2": "blub"
            },
            "tests": [
                "test": 1,
                "test": 2,
                "test": 3
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "settings": {
                "setting1": "bla",
                "setting2": "blub"
            },
            "tests": [
                "test": 1,
                "test": 2,
                "test": 3
            ]
        }
    ],
    "other_prefix": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "values": {
                "value1": "bla",
                "value2": "blub"
            },
            "something": "Hello!"
        }
    ]
}
```

Someone have a good idea how I can do that with PHP, when I read the data from the txt file? The lines are exactly like this, so if necessary I can read every line.

Comment: You are not alone.  Google: "how to parse invalid json in php" you may find a shortcut by adapting someone else's code.  Delete this question because you haven't attempted anything.  Then if you can't get your attempt to work (after proper researching and experimenting) bring your problem back to SO again.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the format that you have in the TXT file is a real format that can be parsed by a PHP function into an object, I am afraid that you will need to write a parser from scratch. It will involve a loop that read line by line, some IFs statments and regular expressions.

Then you can build a hash containing hashes and lists.

And then you can convert this hash to a JSON string using json_encode($myhash).